Geometric proof for a optimization problem about minimizing the weighted sum of distance
Consider a line $r$ and two points, $P$ and $Q$, on the same semi-plane of $r$. The problem is: find point $A$ on $r$ such that $1 \times distance(A,P)+2 \times distance(A,Q)$ is minimal.
(the values 1 and 2 are a particular case. Ideally, it would be nice to find a solution that could be generalized for other values, but a specific solution for this case would be of great help).
Algebraic or numerical solutions are pretty straight forward, but I am looking for a geometrical solution since some variations of this problem admit quite elegant geometrical solutions.

We can convert your geometry problem into an optical propagation problem. More specifically, it's about the the principle of least time in the case of refraction when light propagate from one dielectric medium into another dielectric medium.
I've drawn a diagram to better show this process:
the point $Q'$ and $Q$ is symmetrical about the line.
Let the refractive index of the upper semi-plane is $n_2 = k$,
and the refractive index of the below semi-plane is $n_1 = 1$.
$\theta_1$ is the angle of incidence, and $\theta_2$ is the angle of refraction.

Then the optical path length from point $P$ to point $Q'$ is:
$$
\bf{OPL}_{P\rightarrow Q'} 
= n_{1}\cdot|PA| + n_{2}\cdot|AQ'|
= |PA| + k\cdot|AQ|
$$
According to the principle of least time, a light ray in going from point $P$ to point $Q'$ must propagate with an optical path length that is stationary with respect to variations of that path.
In this case, is to minimize the value of $\bf{OPL}_{P\rightarrow Q'}$
And the condition to arrive this minimum value is the widely known so-called law of refraction (or Snell's law ). Expressed in terms of the formula is:
$$
n_1\sin\theta_1 = n_2\sin\theta_2
$$
As you mentioned, algebraic or numerical solutions are pretty straight forward.
Actually, we can proof the Snell's law using a Calculus approach. (as the figure below shows)

For more details about the 'proof the Snell's law using a Calculus approach', please refer further to this question or this video.

In the answer you linked a geometric proof of Snell's law is given, without calculus. But that proof doesn't use Fermat's minimum principle, hence it is not relevant in this case.

I say that in order to have the minimum value of $PA+2QA$, point $A$ on the given line $r$ must be chosen so that it lies between the projections of $P$ and $Q$ on $r$ and:
$$
\sin\beta=2\sin\alpha,
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the angles formed by rays $AQ$ and $AP$ respectively with the normal to $r$ at $A$ (see figure below).
(And in general, the minimum of $PA+nQA$ is attained when
$\sin\beta=n\sin\alpha$).
PROOF.
Construct point $A$ defined above and the circle through $PAQ$. Let $T$ be the the second intersection of the circle with the normal at $A$. Then by Ptolemy's theorem we have:
$$
PA\cdot QT+QA\cdot PT = PQ\cdot AT.
$$
Take now any other point $B\ne A$ on line $r$: I'll show that $PB+2QB>PA+2QA$. Points $PBQT$ are not in general concyclic, hence by Ptolemy's inequality we have:
$$
PB\cdot QT+QB\cdot PT \ge PQ\cdot BT.
$$
But $BT>AT$, hence $PQ\cdot BT>PQ\cdot AT$ and:
$$
PB\cdot QT+QB\cdot PT>PA\cdot QT+QA\cdot PT.
$$
Observe now that $QT$ and $PT$ subtend inscribed angles $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If $R$ is the radius of circle $PAQT$ we have then $QT=2R\sin\alpha$ and $PT=2R\sin\beta$, that is:
$$PT=2QT.$$
Substituting this into the previous inequality and dividing by $QT$ we get then:
$$
PB+2QB>PA+2QA,
$$
which is what we wanted to prove.

